# Which C++ merge module should I include with my VS 2013 application

Tags: c#, c++, wix, runtime, redistributable

I have built a C# application which references a C++ library.  The dependencies for the project are.

.NET Framework 4.5
Visual Studio 2013 C++ Redistributable Package - vcredist_x86.exe

I have tested these components independently on a clean Windows 7 machine by 
1. Copying my client libraries
2. Installing the .NET libraries
3. Installing the 2013 C++ redist pacakge.

I am now looking to build these components into a WIX package and the last step is to install the C++ Redist.

As i understand the best way to do this is to use the MS merge module and reference this in my WIX project.   The help points to obtaining the merge module for the 2013 C++ runtimes from C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules.

I can see various merge modules references VC110, VC120, but there are no version of VC130.   I am using Visual Studio Express 2013.   So my question is

1. Is the approach correct?  Should I be using the merge module?
2. Do i need to ue the VC130 merge modules and were can I locate them.

Answer (score 2):

Using the merge module a fine approach, as you can make the installation of the required redistributables invisible to the user.

You want to use the VC120 merge module. There is no such thing as a VC130 merge module. VC110 and VC120 don't correspond to the years 2011 and 2012. They correspond to 11.0 and 12.0, the internal version numbers for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 respectively.

Link with Visual Studio version numbers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History